# How to find xpath of preceding element

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<div id="r::p:" class="xxx">
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<span class="axn29n">Jul 12, 2017 12:25:54 PM UTC</span>
</div>
<div>
<div id="r:p" style="margin-top:15px"/>
</div>
<div>
<span class="axn29n">2</span>
</div>
<div>
<img id="r:p:pt2:" width="5px" height="0px" alt="" src="images/t.gif"/>
</div>
<div>
<span class="axn29m">Blogs</span>
</div>
```

I need to get xpath of span "2". I want to use preceding-sibling of "Blogs" and retrieve it. Any suggestions

Comment: ...any attempts?

Comment: I tried //div/span[contains(@class,'axn29m') and contains(text(),'Blogs')]/preceding-sibling::div/span[1] but not sure of div/span syntax

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below `XPath` to get `span` with text content `"2"`:

```
//span[.="Logs"]/preceding::span[1]
```

Comment: It didnt work and I need element sibling which is not immediate- I tried //div[contains(@id,'r::p:']//span[contains(text(),'Blogs')]/preceding::span[1]//preceding::span[1] and this one too didnt work. Any suggestions

Comment: What do you mean *didn't work*? Can you share the **exact** `HTML` sample if provided one was simplified? Also share name of tool you use

Comment: <div>
<table id="r1:0:pt1:pt2:rl1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="90%" summary="">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="r1:0:pt1:pt2:cf1">
<div id="r1:0:pt1:pt2:mua" class="x1a">
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<div>
<span class="x29n">2</span>
</div>
<div>
<div>
<span class="x29m">Logs</span>
</div>
<div>

Comment: This is the part of html and I am using firepath

Comment: I used this //div[contains(@id,':mua') or contains(@class,'xla')]/div[7]/span which worked but I need to modify using preceding ie need to get xpath relative to Logs

Comment: This one should do the trick `//span[.="Logs"]/preceding::span[1]`